# how can i extract images from a "900Mb html file" containing base64 data string images

Tags: html, base64, png

i have html file which contains about 4000 images as base64 data string
in this form

```
<div id="results"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA........IwRkIBpBM9">
</div>
```

how can i extract every image in the file as a numbered images from 1 to 4000 or so.

i couldn't find a way to download all the images using any available software and the html is not being opened with notepad++ because file is too big so i do not have an easy way to edit the codes

thanks for help

Comment: Does your src attribute contain 4000 images? How are they divided? Could you provide an example of at least two images?

Comment: it ends and starts the next one   EAAAAAASUVORK5CYII="><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg